# Can MySQL concatenate strings with ||

Tags: mysql, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm using sqlite3 for the moment, and hence concatenation strings using the `||` operator.

At some later date I'd like to shift to MySQL, and hence it would be nice if no changes to the code had to be made. I'd normally use `concat()` to concatenate in MySQL. Does `||` work too, or will I have to modify my code? Or is there any other solution?

I'm coding in Ruby on Rails 3.1, by the way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `||` works in MySQL as well but you need to set `sql_mode` to `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`.

[Official Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or)

Demo:

```
mysql> select c from tmp;
+------+
| c    |
+------+
| foo  |
| bar  |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select c||' hi' from tmp;
+----------+
| c||' hi' |
+----------+
|        0 |
|        0 |
+----------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> set sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select c||' hi' from tmp;
+----------+
| c||' hi' |
+----------+
| foo hi   |
| bar hi   |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is also included when running in `ansi` mode (which is something I highly recommend): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi

Comment: The previous ANSI mode comment has a dead link; use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/compatibility.html