# How to display two columns of different types in one column?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to display two columns of different types or two column data of same type that will be displayed in one column.

The types are `date + time`, or `varchar + varchar` etc

I know how to concat strings (add a string to one column) but can't seem to do it for two columns data.

Say I want to display two columns both varchar type, fname + lname = Ajay Punja

Or

```
Lname + DOB = Punja 01/01/2001
```

I tried using single and double pipes, plus signs etc but always returns 0.

Is it because I need to convert two different data types into one matching data type? But, both varchar types returns 0.

Comment: [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is how concatenations are done in MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can MySQL concatenate strings with ||](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212192/can-mysql-concatenate-strings-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will help you.

```
SELECT CONCAT(2, ' test') as result form table_name;
```

It is also possible to convert a number to a string explicitly using the `CAST()` function. Conversion occurs implicitly with the `CONCAT()` function because it expects string arguments. e.g.

```
SELECT 38.8, CAST(38.8 AS CHAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

**My answer thanks to everyone here :)**

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', DOB) as Results FROM Person;
SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) as Results FROM Person;
```

Now I understand how to use CONCAT properly. Before I thought for each bracket it must contain only one attribute (or string) and then CONCAT it with enough bracket of data, but clearly that's wrong.

**Wrong example (fail attempt):**

SELECT CONCAT(fname, '') + (' ', lname)) as Results FROM Person;